# TypeError: 'itertools.combinations' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-itertools

When I try to run:

```
temp = (twoset2[x][i][0]-twoset[x][i][1])
```

I get:

> TypeError: 'itertools.combinations' object is not subscriptable

My code:

```
for x in range(0,64):
    for i in range(0,1):
        temp = (twoset2[x][i][0]-twoset[x][i][1])
        DSET[counter2]= temp
        temp = 0
        counter2 += 1
```

Basically what I am trying to do is: I have a list (`twoset2`) of 2 element subsets of coordinates (so an example: `((2,0) (3,3)`). I want to access each individual coordinate, and then take the difference between `x` and `y` and place it into `DSET`, but I get the above error when trying to run.

Please help!

Comment: where is `itertools.combinations()` in your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) returns a generator and not a list. What this means is that you can iterate over it but not access it element by element with an index as you are attempting to.

Instead you can get each combination like so:

```
import itertools
for combination in itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 2):
    print combination
```

This gives:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
```

Comment: `a,b=combination` is not necessary

Answer (score 5):

`twoset2` is not a list; it is an `itertools.combinations` object (which does not support indexing):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3], 2)
<itertools.combinations object at 0x01ACDC30>
>>>
>>> twoset2 = itertools.combinations([1, 2, 3], 2)
>>> twoset2[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'itertools.combinations' object is not subscriptable
>>>
```

You will need to explicitly convert this into a list if you want a list:

```
twoset2 = list(itertools.combinations(...))
```