# Get Tuple Index from itertool.combination list

Tags: python, list, tuples, combinations, python-itertools

Good morning to all

Im trying to insert in variable x and y the index[0] and index [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199603/typeerror-itertools-combinations-object-is-not-subscriptable) from a list of tuples generate by the itertools.combination function

In these link ['itertools.combinations' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199603/typeerror-itertools-combinations-object-is-not-subscriptable)I found that objects from combination are not subscriptable and will like to know if there´s a way to get the separate tuples index into the function

```
a = [10,11,12,13,14,15]
b = combinations(a,2)

x= b[0]
y= b[1]

conditions = [df[f'sma_{x}'] > df[f'sma_{y}'],
              df[f'sma_{x}'] < df[f'sma_{y}']]

choices = [1, -1]

df[f'sma_{x} & sma_{y}'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itertools.combinations` return a generator expression.

If you want to access an index of the result of `combinations` you have to 'consume' it with `list`:

```py
a = [10,11,12,13,14,15]
b = list(combinations(a,2))

x= b[0]
y= b[1]

conditions = [df[f'sma_{x}'] > df[f'sma_{y}'],
              df[f'sma_{x}'] < df[f'sma_{y}']]

choices = [1, -1]

df[f'sma_{x} & sma_{y}'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, I just did but when I print the x and Y variable I got: (10, 11)
(10, 12) that generate an error when I upload these tuple into the functions. As an example I need: to get the next  values for the function:                                                                  
                                                                                                                                 
      conditions = [df[f'sma_{10}'] > df[f'sma_{11}'],
                            df[f'sma_{10}'] < df[f'sma_{11}']]

Comment: Ok, then just use the tuple `x` and index it: [df[f'sma_{x[0]}'] > df[f'sma_{x[1]}'], df[f'sma_{x[0]}'] < df[f'sma_{x[1]}']]

Comment: This will not be practical for any large number of indices in `a`, but it's a fast way to deal with a small one-off problem.